# The simplest way to generate a drone note or chord on the Mac

Tags: practice, synthesizer, mac

... a simple virtual instrument or utility that can hold a chord or note, on MacOS / OSX ?

Preferably, free software.

A lightweight, self-contained solution would be best; a simple VST/AU plugin will work too.

Thanks.

Comment: You can create this type of tool in [jmax](http://jmax.sourceforge.net/), a free visual programming system for music.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that there's probably a "web audio" project (meaning it's just a web page built with JavaScript) that can do it. For instance here's an arpeggiator:

https://codepen.io/jakealbaugh/full/qNrZyw/

There are lot of other web audio projects like that and I'm sure there's probably one to do whatever you need. But I see so many of them and don't bookmark them so I can't recommend anything more specific than googling webaudio + {tool} or taking a look a [Audiocrawl.co](http://audiocrawl.co/) or browsing through similar lists: [(1)](https://codepen.io/tag/webaudio/) [(2)](https://github.com/notthetup/awesome-webaudio) [(3)](https://github.com/alemangui/web-audio-resources) [(4)](http://webaudio.github.io/demo-list/).

Other than that there are free programs similar to [Band-in-a-box](http://www.pgmusic.com/) like [Impro-Visor](https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~keller/jazz/improvisor/) and [MMA](http://www.mellowood.ca/mma/). I can't speak to how good they are because I use BIAB. On mobile, [Chordbot](http://www.chordbot.com/) is a decent BIAB-type app.

With scoring software like [Musescore](https://musescore.org/en) (free) you could loop the playback of a measure or however long a phrase you need.

Personally, I tend to use either a hardware looper (and can just loop guitar or bass), my DAW that is usually already open, or BIAB. But I understand the need for a lightweight solution and I'd say a web page—if you can find one that meets your needs—is about as lightweight as you're going to get.

Comment: Thank you - Interesting tips, but no solution so far. I don't care for web pages; otherwise, this would nearly suffice: http://www.dronetonetool.com/

Comment: The rest of the stuff is not at all lightweight. However, if there is no simple standalone utility, then a *description* of a simple way to do this using a DAW (with a simple and ideally free plugin) would be the next best thing.

Comment: A description of what you want to use it for might help others suggest tools. Is this just for practice or for live performance (where the network requirement and unreliability of a web page is dealbreaker)? And what are you practicing? Do you need just a single note/chord or are you playing over chord changes etc? For instance, I use such tools mostly for playing over entire progressions of chord changes mostly in a jazz-like context. What's your use case?

Comment: The description of how to do it with a DAW depends heavily on your DAW. But generally it's a simple as setting some loop markers, hitting record, and playing a note/chord (or drawing one in). But your DAW is probably comparable if not more resource-intensive than say Musescore or a BIAB clone. In my case, it's just that I keep it open anyway because I use it so much. This is also what makes a web page quick and lightweight. You probably already have a browser open so loading a new page only takes seconds and very little additional memory.

Answer (score 0):

My CoreMIDI Library for LiveCode (HyperCard clone descendant, AppleScript-like) can do this, or whatever you want really with a little effort.